# DateTime picker C# format

Tags: c#, datetime, wpftoolkit

I have a `DateTime` picker to add arrival time to a list, I have 2 questions about it:

1. How can I get it to show dates like `12-Jan-2012` Instead of `12/01/12`?
2. How can I get it to show the time after the date but not the current time, as thats what is shows atm.

My current code is not very advanced its just:

```
theVisit.ArrivalTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this will display the date and time:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

To override the default DateTimePicker settings, you can do this:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "d-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss";
```

You can show a different time by modifying the format string, e.g.:

```
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "d-MMM-yyyy 12:00:00";
```

or even

```
DateTime otherTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "d-MMM-yyyy " + otherTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @<Peter Gluck> Hey, I am getting the error can't implicitly convert type string to system.datetime

Answer (score 3):

For it to show in that format in the picker, set the properties below

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy  hh:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for DateTime Format strings. There's a great article on them on MSDN.
There's two types:

1. [Standard DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
2. [Custom DateTime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

You can use these to construct the datetime to look how you want it to. 
For your example, you would use :

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to alter how your DateTimePicker displays DateTimes:

```
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
DateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Your code:

```
theVisit.ArrivalTime = DateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Would not change, because the `DateTimePicker1.Value` isn't any different, it's just displayed according to your format.

If you want the control to display a specific time (not the current time), you have to give the control that value:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2012, 12, 21, 23, 59, 59);
```

Otherwise it will display the current time as of the form creation.

Answer (score 0):

You may check `datetimepicker` like this to check if it is empty.

```
if(DatTimePicker1.Text.Equals(" "))
{
     MessageBox.Show("DateTimePicker is empty");
}
```