# How to get string value from date time picker specific date setting

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetimepicker

I'm trying to set date with date time picker this way `year/month/day`. I don't want get current time:

```
label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I'm trying to set the range between given specific dates, for example from 1970/1/2 to 1980/4/2

so the only thing I'm trying is to get the string value as it is "1970/1/2" or integer. It does not matter if it is formatted separately with slashes or with dots (1970.1.2). It must be equal to settings with date time picker as it is given by the user in GUI, to process this range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime picker C# format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711358/datetime-picker-c-sharp-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the format of your datetime picker. This can be done using the .Format property

```
public void SetMyCustomFormat()
{
   // Set the Format type and the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
}
```

More info can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Beat me to it, but that might be because you copy pasted it haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom format:

```
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```